# Performance alternative over Scripting.Dictionary

Tags: excel, dictionary, vba

I am coding a Manager in Excel-VBA with several buttons.

One of them is to generate a tab using another Excel file (let me call it `T`) as input.

Some properties of `T`:

- `~90MB` size
- `~350K` lines
- Contains **sales** data of the last `14` months (unordered).
- Relevant columns:

  - `year/month`
  - total-money
  - seller-name
  - family-product
  - client-name
- There is not id columns (like: cod-client, cod-vendor, etc.)

Main relation:

- Sellers sells many Products to many Clients

I am generating a new Excel tab with data from `T` of the last `year/month` grouped by Seller.

Important notes:

- `T` is the only available input/source.
- If two or more Sellers sells the same Product to the same Client, the `total-money` should be counted to all of those Sellers.

---

This is enough, now you know what I have **already coded**.

My code works, **but**, it takes about 4 minutes of runtime.

I have already coded some other buttons using smaller sources (not greater than `2MB`) which runs in 5 seconds.

*Considering `T` size, 4 minutes runtime could be acceptable*.

But I'm not proud of it, at least not yet.

---

My code is mainly based on `Scripting.Dictionary` to map data from `T`, and then I use `for each key in obj ... next key` to set the grouped data to the new created tab.

I'm not sure, but here are my thoughts:

- If `N` is the total keys in a `Scripting.Dictionary`, and I need to check for `obj.Exists(str)` before aggregating `total-money`. It will run `N` string compares to return `false`.
- Similarly it will run maximun `N` string compares when I do `Set seller = obj(seller_name)`.

---

I want to be wrong with my thoughts. But if I'm not wrong, my next step (and last hope) to reduce the runtime of this function is to *code my own class object* with [`Tries`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

I will only start coding tomorrow, what I want is just some confirmation if I am in the right way, or some advices if I am in the wrong way of doing it.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: since you have working code but want improvements, is this question a better candidate for the code review site?

Comment: This question, as written, is out of scope for SO. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info. As @sous2817 suggest, please try [Code Review](http://stackexchange.codereview.com) *if your code is 100% working*).

Comment: However, you should first read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users). And refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12226218/7690982) and [Efficiency and Performance](http://www.avdf.com/apr98/art_ot003.html)

Comment: It would be better to use SQL. Try adodb.

Comment: Rhetorical question: What are you using `Dictionary` for that can't be accomplished by an array? If your concern is performance, arrays are hard to beat unless you *need* some feature like key look-up.

Comment: @Vegard I indeed need to look up keys. Otherwise, how could I sum up values (`total-money`) by Seller names?

Comment: @DyLee Certainly it would be better, unlucky I can't.

Comment: @danieltakeshi. Really interesting posts you linked here. I am commuting right now, and I will most probably start coding my dictionary class using Tries soon. @ sous2817, ScottHoltzman. Regarding CodeReview, I didn't post there because I was just wondering if my thoughts were right, or even if someone had such a problem before and handled it in a different way, I'm not giving some code asking to improve it.   When and if I get to reduce runtime I will post an answer.

Comment: the only downsides on dictionary, is that every key must be unique, and that you can't read a big range in one line like you would in an array.
But it's faster for working with, and has methods like `.exists`and `.remove`.
Basically i always use dictionary, unless there are not unique keys, or i work on small range.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes How many unique sellers do you estimate that you have?

Comment: @Vegard. About 200

Comment: That is a very low number for 4 minutes execution time. I get ~0 to ~1 seconds execution time when I have 600k lines and 500 unique sellers. It sounds more and more like your bottleneck is not in `Dictionary` at all.

Comment: @Vegard. It may be true. I have already coded my `cls_trie`, I am now updating my code to use it instead of `Scripting.Dictionary`, in a while I can confirm it.

Comment: No what I mean is, `Dictionary` does not appear to be the problem. If you have long execution time with it, you will probably have long execution time with other methods as well - because the bottleneck is not in this part of the code.

Comment: @Vegard. I got you... I know it is just seconds to traverse the `350k lines`, but there is dictionaries for clients and products, not only sellers. This is why I think `Dictionary` _may_ be the problem. But, of course, if my `cls_trie` still fail, I will need to review my entire logic again.

Comment: 5.5 hours changing my code, and the result was that my `cls_trie` takes ~3 minutes :/ ... I need some time to think, maybe pivot tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Memory Limit Exceeded**

In short:

- The main problem was because I used a dynamic programming approach of storing information (preprocessing) to make the execution time faster.
- My code now runs in `~ 13 seconds`.

---

There are things we learn the hard way. But I'm glad I found the answer.

- Using the Task Manager I was able to see my code reaching 100% memory usage.
- The DP approach I mentioned above using `Scripting.Dictionary` reached 100% really faster.
- The DP approach I mentioned above using my own `cls_trie` implementation also reached 100%, but later than the first.
- This explains the `~4-5 min` compared to `~2-3 min` total runtime of above attempts.
- In the Task Manager I could also see that the CPU usage never hited `2%`.

Solution was simple, I had to balance CPU and Memory usages.

- I changed some DP approaches to simple `for-loops` with `if-conditions`.
- The CPU usage now hits `~15%`.
- The Memory usage now hits `~65%`.
- I know this is relative to the CPU and Memory capacity of each machine. But in the client machine it is also running in no more than `15 seconds` now.

---

I created one [GitHub repository with my cls_trie implementation](https://github.com/WashingtonGuedes/excel-vba-cls-trie) and added one excel file with an example usage.

I'm new to the excel-vba world (4 months working with it right now). There might probably have some ways to improve my cls_trie implementation, I'm openned to suggestions:

```
Option Explicit

Public Keys As Collection
Public Children As Variant
Public IsLeaf As Boolean

Public tObject As Variant
Public tValue As Variant

Public Sub Init()
    Set Keys = New Collection
    ReDim Children(0 To 255) As cls_trie
    IsLeaf = False

    Set tObject = Nothing
    tValue = 0
End Sub

Public Function GetNodeAt(index As Integer) As cls_trie
    Set GetNodeAt = Children(index)
End Function

Public Sub CreateNodeAt(index As Integer)
    Set Children(index) = New cls_trie
    Children(index).Init
End Sub

'''
'Following function will retrieve node for a given key,
'creating a entire new branch if necessary
'''
Public Function GetNode(ByRef key As Variant) As cls_trie
    Dim node As cls_trie
    Dim b() As Byte
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim pos As Integer

    b = CStr(key)
    Set node = Me

    For i = 0 To UBound(b) Step 2
        pos = b(i) Mod 256

        If (node.GetNodeAt(pos) Is Nothing) Then
            node.CreateNodeAt pos
        End If

        Set node = node.GetNodeAt(pos)
    Next

    If (node.IsLeaf) Then
        'already existed
    Else
        node.IsLeaf = True
        Keys.Add key
    End If

    Set GetNode = node
End Function

'''
'Following function will get the value for a given key
'Creating the key if necessary
'''
Public Function GetValue(ByRef key As Variant) As Variant
    Dim node As cls_trie
    Set node = GetNode(key)
    GetValue = node.tValue
End Function

'''
'Following sub will set a value to a given key
'Creating the key if necessary
'''
Public Sub SetValue(ByRef key As Variant, value As Variant)
    Dim node As cls_trie
    Set node = GetNode(key)
    node.tValue = value
End Sub

'''
'Following sub will sum up a value for a given key
'Creating the key if necessary
'''
Public Sub SumValue(ByRef key As Variant, value As Variant)
    Dim node As cls_trie
    Set node = GetNode(key)
    node.tValue = node.tValue + value
End Sub

'''
'Following function will validate if given key exists
'''
Public Function Exists(ByRef key As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim node As cls_trie
    Dim b() As Byte
    Dim i As Integer

    b = CStr(key)
    Set node = Me

    For i = 0 To UBound(b) Step 2
        Set node = node.GetNodeAt(b(i) Mod 256)

        If (node Is Nothing) Then
            Exists = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    Exists = node.IsLeaf
End Function

'''
'Following function will get another Trie from given key
'Creating both key and trie if necessary
'''
Public Function GetTrie(ByRef key As Variant) As cls_trie
    Dim node As cls_trie
    Set node = GetNode(key)

    If (node.tObject Is Nothing) Then
        Set node.tObject = New cls_trie
        node.tObject.Init
    End If

    Set GetTrie = node.tObject
End Function
```

You can see in the above code:

- I hadn't implemented any delete method because I didn't need it till now. But it would be easy to implement.
- I limited myself to 256 children because in this project the text I'm working on is basically lowercase and uppercase `[a-z]` letters and numbers, and the probability that two text get mapped to the same branch node tends zero.

---

> as a great coder said, everyone likes his own code even if other's code is too beautiful to be disliked [<sup>[1]</sup>](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/116935/unofficial-editorials-november-long-challenge-part-2#comment-116966)

My conclusion

- I will probably never more use `Scripting.Dictionary`, even if it is proven that somehow it could be better than my `cls_trie` implementation.

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm convinced that you've already found the right solution because there wasn't any update for last two years.

Anyhow, I want to mention (maybe it will help someone else) that your bottleneck isn't the Dictionary or Binary Tree. Even with millions of rows the processing in memory is blazingly fast if you have sufficient amount of RAM.

The botlleneck is usually the reading of data from worksheet and writing it back to the worksheet. Here the arrays come very userfull.

Just read the data from worksheet into the Variant Array.
You don't have to work with that array right away. If it is more comfortable for you to work with dictionary, just transfer all the data from array into dictionary and work with it. Since this process is entirely made in memory, don't worry about the performance penalisation.

When you are finished with data processing in dictionary, put all data from dictionary back to the array and write that array into a new worksheet at one shot.

Worksheets("New Sheet").Range("A1").Value = MyArray

I'm pretty sure it will take only few seconds